# What is a cascaded convolutional neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, definitions, papers

For a project I am doing, I found the paper [Face Alignment in Full Pose Range: A 3D Total Solution](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.01005.pdf).

It is using a cascaded convolutional neural network, but I wasn't able to find the original paper explaining what that is.

In layman's terms and intuitively, how does a cascaded CNN work? What does it solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.01005.pdf) you are citing is the paper that introduced the [cascaded](https://pdollar.github.io/files/papers/DollarCVPR10pose.pdf) convolution neural network. In fact, in this paper, the authors say

> To realize 3DDFA, we propose to **combine two achievements** in recent years, namely, **Cascaded Regression** and the **Convolutional Neural Network** (CNN). This combination requires the introduction of a new input feature which fulfills the "cascade manner" and "convolution manner" simultaneously (see Sec. 3.2) and a new cost function which can model the priority of 3DMM parameters (see Sec. 3.4)

where 3DDFA stands for **3D Dense Face Alignment**, the framework proposed in this paper for **face alignment**, in which a dense [**3D Morphable Model** (3DMM)](https://gravis.dmi.unibas.ch/publications/pami03.pdf) is fitted to the image via cascaded CNNs (the [regressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis)), where the term *dense* refers to the number of points of the face that will be modeled. See figure 1 of this paper, which should provide some intuition behind the purpose of this framework.

In section 3 (page 3), they also say

> In this section, we introduce how to combine Cascaded Regression and CNNs to realize 3DDFA. By applying a CNN as the regressor in Eqn. 1, Cascaded CNN can be formulated as:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{p}^{k+1} = \mathbf{p}^{k} + \text{Net}^{k}
(\text{Fea}(\mathbf{I}, \mathbf{p}^k)) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

where

- $k$ is the iteration number
- $\mathbf{p}$ is the regression objective
- $\text{Net}$ is the CNN structure
- $\text{Fea}$ contains the two constructed image features

  - Pose Adaptive Feature (PAF) (section 3.2.1)
  - Projected Normalized Coordinate Code (PNCC) (section 3.2.2)
- $\mathbf{I}$ is the image

The expression *[cascaded](https://pdollar.github.io/files/papers/DollarCVPR10pose.pdf) CNN* apparently refers to the fact that equation \ref{1} is used iteratively, so there will be multiple CNNs, one for each iteration $k$. In fact, in the paper, they say

> Unlike existing CNN methods that apply different network structures for different fitting stages, 3DDFA employs a unified network structure across the cascade. In general, at iteration $k$ ($k = 0, 1, \dots, K$), given an initial parameter $\mathbf{p}^k$, we construct PNCC and PAF with $\mathbf{p}^k$ and train a two-stream CNN $\text{Net}^k$ to conduct fitting. The output features from two streams are merged to predict the parameter update $\Delta \mathbf{p}^k$
>
> $$
> \Delta \mathbf{p}^k = \text{Net}^k(\text{PAF}(\mathbf{p}^k, \mathbf{I}), \text{PNCC}(\mathbf{p}^k, \mathbf{I}))
> $$
>
> Afterwards, a better **intermediate** parameter $\mathbf{p}^{k+1} = \mathbf{p}^k + \Delta \mathbf{p}^k$ becomes the input of the next network $\text{Net}^k$ which has the **same structure but different weights with $\text{Net}^k$**.

In [figure 2 of the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.01005.pdf) (page 4), the structure of this two-stream CNN, $\text{Net}^k$, at iteration $k$, is shown.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with this cascade CNN. I only quickly read certain parts of the paper and I tried to provide some intuition behind it. Maybe later I will refine this answer to provide even more intuition.